# Generate Paper Wallet using Electrum

Tags: electrum, paper-wallet

**Question:** How do I generate a BTC paper wallet from an Electrum wallet.

**Context:** I have created a new wallet in Electrum and transferred a small amount of BTC there. That is the only transaction that has occurred in that wallet.
I would now like to use the contents of that wallet to generate a paper wallet for that full amount, and ideally do it all through the Electrum application. The reason why I want this as a paper wallet is that I want to give it as a gift for my nephew to have when they turn 21 in 20 years time. Having a nice laminated paper wallet seems both safer and cooler than placing a copy of the wallet on a USB stick or something else. Perhaps BTC will still be worth something then, or perhaps it won't even exist, but either way it will be an interesting thing for my future 21 year nephew to discover!

**Note:**

- I am a complete newbe, so please explain everything.
- If what I am asking is totally impossible using Electrum alone, please tell me the simplest and safest alternative.
- I am using Electrum on a Mac.

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write everything on a piece of paper or print it if printer is not connected to internet. Things that should be written on paper for successful recovery later:

1. Seed phrase
2. Derivation path
3. Electrum version

You can also try descriptor based paper wallets however I am not sure if Electrum supports descriptors yet:

https://bitcoindevkit.org/blog/2021/03/descriptor-based-paper-wallets/

Comment: Thanks for that info! 

I just have a couple of questions:

Is the derivation path the same as the private key? 

And secondly, if Electrum is not supported in the future, is there there other information I should put in a paper wallet so that it can be accessed in some way that doesn't rely on Electrum?

Thanks again for your help! :)